# How do I receive Server Side Events with PHP (without Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am attempting to create a bot that monitors the live feed from a live video on a Facebook page that can help answer simple questions.

So far, I have found ***Server-Side Events (SSEs)*** to be the most efficient way of retrieving these comments, however I have yet to find a way to receive them short of using a separate computer for running the ***Javascript (JS)*** and then sending that data over ***AJAX*** to my php script.

Is there any way for me to receive ***SSEs*** without using ***JS***, preferably at an endpoint?

EDIT:
A couple of things to note.

I am attempting to do this on a Wordpress site with an Endpoint. Basically, when something is posted to the endpoint (like a webhook notification about a video going live), the script would run, requesting the SSEs for the comments of the live video to establish a connection with Facebook.

Comment: take a look at [php curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cURL` in PHP to access remote resources. Here's a example of a simple `cURL` connection:

```
<?php 
        // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $output = curl_exec($ch); 

        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);      
?>
```

The `cURL` works a lot like an AJAX call except `cURL` is executed synchronously and runs on the server.

Comment: When I use curl (through Wordpress with the wordpress function for curl "wp_remote_request"), it times out with a "cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received" error. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: @Kyris Maybe check to see if `cURL` is installed on your server. Run this command on your server to check the version `curl --version`. If you are using ubuntu you should be able to run this command to install it `sudo apt-get install curl`

Comment: I know that curl is installed and working okay since using wp_remote_request works when requesting google.com. What's happening is a request to the endpoint (In this case, me loading the endpoint url in my browser) and then the script for the endpoint runs. The browser continues to load until the timeout time is up, regardless if any data has transferred in that time period. I need it to  maintain the connection until the stream ends, and to run a script when a comment is passed back during the stream. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not something you would want to execute in a browser Kyris. This is something you would want a cron job to execute every so often and check if the CURL response changed. If it has, there is your event.